# Azure Data Factory Exist Transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way that after comparing two tables and then use the Case function?

I am trying to have a new column base on Exists transformation. In sql I do it like this:

```
(isnull (select 'YES' from sales where salesperson = t1.salesperson group by salesperson), 'NO')) AS registeredSales

T1 is personal.
```

Or should I include the table into the stream of the joins and then use the case() function to compare the two columns?

If there's another way to work around to compare these two streams, I would be pleased to hear.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Luis Jacobo, I've tested my answer and it works. We can use derived column to generate a  new column. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer, very thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flat files in a datalake can also be compared. We can use the [derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) in dataflow to gernerate a new column.

1. I create a dataflow demo cotains two sources:  **CustomerSource**(customer.csv stored in datalake2) and **SalesSource**(sales.csv stored in datalake2 and it contains only one column) as follows

[image]

2. Then I join the two sources with the column **CustomerId**

[image]

3. Then I use **Select** activity to give an alias to the **CustomerId** from **SalesSource**

[image]

4. In the **DerivedColumn**, I select the **Add column** and enter the expression `iifNull(SalesCustomerID, 'NO', 'YES')` to generate a new column named 'registeredSales' as follows:
   [image]
5. The last column of the result shows:

[image]

Comment: All the sources are flat files in a datalake, so i can't make that query in the source definition. Can I use the same iifnull() function in the same way joining the two sources and then comparing?

Comment: Is your file in csv format? It can also be compared, please see my updated answer.

Comment: registeredSales is the new column and is not part from the joined stream, but you used the expression iifNull() with that column and when you try it to build the expression, cant find that column.

Comment: We can gernerate the registeredSales column that created by DerivedColumn activity. Please see my updated answer.